# Programs hangs on parallelism, Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to make a program that uses parallel.foreach to find a particular string in files of a particular directory and its sub directories, it works fine for about 90% of the iteration but after that the program hangs, and doesn't do any thing.

```
private void searchParallel()
{
    directories.Clear();
    lbResults.Items.Clear();
    if (cbDirectory.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        getAllDirectories(cbDirectory.Text);

        pbSearchProgress.Maximum = directories.Count;
        pbSearchProgress.Minimum = 0;
        pbSearchProgress.Value = 0;
        //foreach (String dir in directories)
        ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
        options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10;
        Parallel.ForEach(directories,options, (dir) =>
        {
            try
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(dir.ToString());
                String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);

                foreach (String file in files)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(file.ToString());

                    if (checkFilePermission(file))
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
                        //MessageBox.Show(file);
                        int lineCount = 0;
                        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
                        {
                            Application.DoEvents();
                            String line = reader.ReadLine();
                            lineCount++;
                            if (line.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower()))
                            {
                                updateList(file, lineCount);
                            }
                            if (isSearching == false)
                            {


                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //if (isSearching == false)
                    //{
                    //    break;
                    //}
                }
                pbMakeProgress();
                //if (isSearching == false)
                //{
                //    loopState.Stop();
                //}
                //MessageBox.Show("Search Completed.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

        });
    }
}
private void updateList(String file, int lineCount)
{
    if (lbResults.InvokeRequired)
    {
        listDelegate lstDelegate = new listDelegate(updateList);
        lbResults.Invoke(lstDelegate, new object[] { file, lineCount });

    }
    else
    {
        lbResults.Items.Add("Found in " + file + " at line: " + lineCount);
    }

}

private void pbMakeProgress()
{
    if (pbSearchProgress.InvokeRequired)
    {
        pbSearchProgress.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(pbMakeProgress));
    }
    else
    {
        pbSearchProgress.Value++;
    }
}
```

pbMakeProgress updates the value of a progress bar,
updateList updates the list box,
getAllDirectories gets the subdirectories,
directories is the list containing the names of all the folders which are to be traversed.

Comment: That `Application.DoEvents()` should be a *huge* warning flag.  If you're doing that, then chances are, you're doing something wrong.  Generally, you'll want to post the updates to the UI thread through a `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: what should I then do to make UI responsive?

Comment: Note the reference to `SynchronizationContext` in the first comment, that, and run this on another thread.

Comment: but let me tell you that I am performing the same task with no parallelism and using the Application.DoEvents() there as well, but it works fine. Any particular reason?

Comment: Couldn't tell you, but you shouldn't be using `Application.DoEvents` generally, it's a hack to get around not parallelizing code.  If you're going to parallelize your code, then you absolutely should *not* use `Application.DoEvents`.

Comment: Could you simplify your code so that it still shows the problem, but doesn't contain anything unrelated to it?

Comment: I would note that I also see StreamReader's created and opened, but not closed or disposed - this is another red flag for me.

Comment: Now using the separate thread for the UI, removed the Application.DoEvents(), works fine.
Thanks